# CheckedListBox iterate over items

Tags: winforms, checkedlistbox

So I'm iterating through all the checked items in the box like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{

}
```

This works but how do I access the display name property of each of the checked items as I get to it. Seems simple but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb.aspx) property to customize the way your items are rendered, you only need to call their [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method:

```
foreach (object item in listFiles.CheckedItems) {
    string displayName = item.ToString();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but this gives the checked state of the

Answer (score 1):

```
     foreach (string itemName in listFiles.CheckedItems)
     {


     }
```